# Conditional Validations based on hidden_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, conditional-statements

In my form I use:
        `<%= hidden_field_tag :formtemplate, "newuser" %>`

Based on this condition I want to validate in my model:

```
    validates_format_of :email, :supervisor, :with => /^([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i, :message => "Adresse überprüfen.", :if => :newuser_formtemplate?
```

Here is newuser_formtemplate?

```
def newuser_formtemplate?
    newuser_formtemplate = "newuser"
    newuser_formtemplate == "newuser"
end
```

How would I have to change this to make it validate based on the hidden__field_tag?

Comment: To attract more answers, you should add a tag corresponding to the language or tools you are using. You can do that by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11646348/edit) and adding tags at the bottom of the edit page.

Comment: Thanks. I did just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use attr_accessor in your model

```
attr_accessor :formtemplate

def newuser_formtemplate?
    newuser_formtemplate = self.formtemplate
    newuser_formtemplate == "newuser"
end
```

If you are using `form_for` in your view then use form object

```
<%= form.hidden_field :formtemplate, "newuser" %>
```

Comment: I think that´s what I want. But I get: undefined local variable or method `form' for #<#<Class:0xb55d26bc>:0xb55d0e98> when I use the form.hidden_field. And as you correctly assumed I´m in a form_for.

Comment: In previous comment I'm using `form`. You might used different name there. So replace `form` with that name.

Comment: Yea...obvious. Sorry. I will accept this answer as it was exactly what I was looking.

Answer (score 0):

How about using new_record? helper from activerecord instead of using hidden field

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F

```
validates_format_of :email, :supervisor, :with => /^([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i, :message => "Adresse überprüfen.", :if => :new_record?
```

Comment: I have different formpartials that use different fields. I use the hidden_field to  determine where the user is coming from and want to validate accordingly. I didn´t know about new_record? and will look into it. But I don´t think it´s what I need, here.